# Extracting features in fastICA (Matlab)

Tags: matlab, feature-extraction

I am a machine learning beginner and I would really appreciate your help.

I'm trying to use the FastICA MATLAB toolbox and after epic amount of googling and reading documentation about it I am just getting more and more confused.

I am using the [Car Data Set](https://cogcomp.cs.illinois.edu/Data/Car/) and I am using 1000 100x40 images (500 car, 500 not-car). I am using fastica to find the independent components (I will use them to build a car detection system later).

I am running the following code on my train data set:

```
[icasig, A, W] = fastica(Training_Set);
```

A and W are 1000x1000 matrices and icasig is 1000x4000 matrix and as I understand icasig's rows contain the independent components and A is the mixing matrix.

How can I plot the independent components? Can someone explain to me in simple English what is W?

Also another thing that is confusing me is, if I delete some rows in icasig and get for example 300x4000 matrix am I doing feature compression?

If I use a classification algorithm (for example SVM) how can I vary the number of independent components that I am using to train it? I think that rica is perfect for this but unfortunately I don't have the Statistics and Machine Learning Toolbox.

Answer (score 1):

> Can someone explain to me in simple English what is W?

**w** in ICA usually represents a separating matrix. Given a mixed image, **X**, one can get independent components by calculating **wX**. The result, **S**, will usually be another matrix whose size is identical to **X**. Each row of **S** contains data that represent one independent component.

One of the major purposes of using ICA algorithm is to find the separating matrix, **w**. If you have no idea about it, I would suggest you read more literature before carrying on. Even [fast ICA's Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FastICA) page tells you about **w**.

> How can I plot the independent components?

If `icasig` is **S**, you can try the following:

```
icasig = abs(icasig) % take the absolute

% you can add a for loop here to plot all components
component=icasig(1,:) % take the first component
im = reshape(component,[h,w,3]); % h being the height of the image of the component and w being the width
im=uint8 (round(im)); 
figure; imshow(im); 
% end of the for loop. Be prepared to have a lot of pictures poping up.
```

> if I delete some rows in icasig and get for example 300x4000 matrix am I doing feature compression?

If deleting some individual components means feature compression, then yes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I am still confused. I tried to build a classifier using the features obtained from ICA but I am not sure if I am doing it in the right way. The input in svmtran is icasig? And how should I project the test set?

    [icasig, A, W] = fastica(Training_Set);
    SVMStruct = svmtrain(icasig , train_label, 'kernel_function', 'quadratic')
    Group = svmclassify(SVMStruct, Test_Set)

Comment: @Jane I'm not familiar with svm, but it seems you are doing the right thing here. I'm not sure what you mean by projecting test set. I would suggest you to open a new question or edit your original question to include the problem of svm.